# Consulta en blanco, Join MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, join

Hola tengo el siguiente problema: cuando quiero realizar una consulta me da en blanco, ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? así se para futuras consultas, poder resolverlo por mí mismo. ¿Por qué una consulta da en blanco?, ¿no se si tiene algo que ver la sintaxis? ¿Cómo se donde se encuentra el error, si no me aparece error en la consola?

Tengo estas tablas:

```
 CREATE TABLE cliente (
  codigo_cliente INTEGER NOT NULL,
  nombre_cliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  nombre_contacto VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  apellido_contacto VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  telefono VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  fax VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  linea_direccion1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  linea_direccion2 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  region VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  pais VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  codigo_postal VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  codigo_empleado_rep_ventas INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  limite_credito NUMERIC(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo_cliente),
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_empleado_rep_ventas) REFERENCES empleado (codigo_empleado)
);
 
CREATE TABLE pedido (
  codigo_pedido INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fecha_pedido date NOT NULL,
  fecha_esperada date NOT NULL,
  fecha_entrega date DEFAULT NULL,
  estado VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  comentarios TEXT,
  codigo_cliente INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo_pedido),
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_cliente) REFERENCES cliente (codigo_cliente)
);
 
CREATE TABLE pago (
  codigo_cliente INTEGER NOT NULL,
  forma_pago VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  id_transaccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  fecha_pago date NOT NULL,
  total NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo_cliente, id_transaccion),
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_cliente) REFERENCES cliente (codigo_cliente)
);
 
/*Estos son mis Inserts*/
 
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (1,'GoldFish Garden','Daniel G','GoldFish','5556901745','5556901746','False Street 52 2 A',NULL,'San Francisco',NULL,'USA','24006',19,3000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (3,'Gardening Associates','Anne','Wright','5557410345','5557410346','Wall-e Avenue',NULL,'Miami','Miami','USA','24010',19,6000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (4,'Gerudo Valley','Link','Flaute','5552323129','5552323128','Oaks Avenue nº22',NULL,'New York',NULL,'USA','85495',22,12000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (5,'Tendo Garden','Akane','Tendo','55591233210','55591233211','Null Street nº69',NULL,'Miami',NULL,'USA','696969',22,600000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (6,'Lasas S.A.','Antonio','Lasas','34916540145','34914851312','C/Leganes 15',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','28945',8,154310);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (7,'Beragua','Jose','Bermejo','654987321','916549872','C/pintor segundo','Getafe','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28942',11,20000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (8,'Club Golf Puerta del hierro','Paco','Lopez','62456810','919535678','C/sinesio delgado','Madrid','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28930',11,40000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (9,'Naturagua','Guillermo','Rengifo','689234750','916428956','C/majadahonda','Boadilla','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28947',11,32000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (10,'DaraDistribuciones','David','Serrano','675598001','916421756','C/azores','Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28946',11,50000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (11,'Madrileña de riegos','Jose','Tacaño','655983045','916689215','C/Lagañas','Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28943',11,20000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (12,'Lasas S.A.','Antonio','Lasas','34916540145','34914851312','C/Leganes 15',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','28945',8,154310);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (13,'Camunas Jardines S.L.','Pedro','Camunas','34914873241','34914871541','C/Virgenes 45','C/Princesas 2 1ºB','San Lorenzo del Escorial','Madrid','Spain','28145',8,16481);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (14,'Dardena S.A.','Juan','Rodriguez','34912453217','34912484764','C/Nueva York 74',NULL,'Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28003',8,321000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (15,'Jardin de Flores','Javier','Villar','654865643','914538776','C/ Oña 34',NULL,'Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28950',30,40000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (16,'Flores Marivi','Maria','Rodriguez','666555444','912458657','C/Leganes24',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','28945',5,1500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (17,'Flowers, S.A','Beatriz','Fernandez','698754159','978453216','C/Luis Salquillo4',NULL,'Montornes del valles','Barcelona','Spain','24586',5,3500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (18,'Naturajardin','Victoria','Cruz','612343529','916548735','Plaza Magallón 15',NULL,'Madrid','Madrid','Spain','28011',30,5050);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (19,'Golf S.A.','Luis','Martinez','916458762','912354475','C/Estancado',NULL,'Santa cruz de Tenerife','Islas Canarias','Spain','38297',12,30000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (20,'Americh Golf Management SL','Mario','Suarez','964493072','964493063','C/Letardo',NULL,'Barcelona','Cataluña','Spain','12320',12,20000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (21,'Aloha','Cristian','Rodrigez','916485852','914489898','C/Roman 3',NULL,'Canarias','Canarias','Spain','35488',12,50000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (22,'El Prat','Francisco','Camacho','916882323','916493211','Avenida Tibidabo',NULL,'Barcelona','Cataluña','Spain','12320',12,30000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (23,'Sotogrande','Maria','Santillana','915576622','914825645','C/Paseo del Parque',NULL,'Sotogrande','Cadiz','Spain','11310',12,60000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (24,'Vivero Humanes','Federico','Gomez','654987690','916040875','C/Miguel Echegaray 54',NULL,'Humanes','Madrid','Spain','28970',30,7430);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (25,'Fuenla City','Tony','Muñoz Mena','675842139','915483754','C/Callo 52',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','28574',5,4500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (26,'Jardines y Mansiones Cactus SL','Eva María','Sánchez','916877445','914477777','Polígono Industrial Maspalomas, Nº52','Móstoles','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','29874',9,76000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (27,'Jardinerías Matías SL','Matías','San Martín','916544147','917897474','C/Francisco Arce, Nº44','Bustarviejo','Madrid','Madrid','Spain','37845',9,100500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (28,'Agrojardin','Benito','Lopez','675432926','916549264','C/Mar Caspio 43',NULL,'Getafe','Madrid','Spain','28904',30,8040);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (29,'Top Campo','Joseluis','Sanchez','685746512','974315924','C/Ibiza 32',NULL,'Humanes','Madrid','Spain','28574',5,5500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (30,'Jardineria Sara','Sara','Marquez','675124537','912475843','C/Lima 1',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','27584',5,7500);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (31,'Campohermoso','Luis','Jimenez','645925376','916159116','C/Peru 78',NULL,'Fuenlabrada','Madrid','Spain','28945',30,3250);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (32,'france telecom','FraÃ§ois','Toulou','(33)5120578961','(33)5120578961','6 place d Alleray 15Ã¨me',NULL,'Paris',NULL,'France','75010',16,10000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (33,'Musée du Louvre','Pierre','Delacroux','(33)0140205050','(33)0140205442','Quai du Louvre',NULL,'Paris',NULL,'France','75058',16,30000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (35,'Tutifruti S.A','Jacob','Jones','2 9261-2433','2 9283-1695','level 24, St. Martins Tower.-31 Market St.',NULL,'Sydney','Nueva Gales del Sur','Australia','2000',31,10000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (36,'Flores S.L.','Antonio','Romero','654352981','685249700','Avenida España',NULL,'Madrid','Fuenlabrada','Spain','29643',18,6000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (37,'The Magic Garden','Richard','Mcain','926523468','9364875882','Lihgting Park',NULL,'London','London','United Kingdom','65930',18,10000);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (38,'El Jardin Viviente S.L','Justin','Smith','2 8005-7161','2 8005-7162','176 Cumberland Street The rocks',NULL,'Sydney','Nueva Gales del Sur','Australia','2003',31,8000);
 
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (1,'2006-01-17','2006-01-19','2006-01-19','Entregado','Pagado a plazos',5);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (2,'2007-10-23','2007-10-28','2007-10-26','Entregado','La entrega llego antes de lo esperado',5);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (3,'2008-06-20','2008-06-25',NULL,'Rechazado','Limite de credito superado',5);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (4,'2009-01-20','2009-01-26',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,5);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (8,'2008-11-09','2008-11-14','2008-11-14','Entregado','El cliente paga la mitad con tarjeta y la otra mitad con efectivo, se le realizan dos facturas',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (9,'2008-12-22','2008-12-27','2008-12-28','Entregado','El cliente comprueba la integridad del paquete, todo correcto',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (10,'2009-01-15','2009-01-20',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente llama para confirmar la fecha - Esperando al proveedor',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (11,'2009-01-20','2009-01-27',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente requiere que el pedido se le entregue de 16:00h a 22:00h',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (12,'2009-01-22','2009-01-27',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente requiere que el pedido se le entregue de 9:00h a 13:00h',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (13,'2009-01-12','2009-01-14','2009-01-15','Entregado',NULL,7);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (14,'2009-01-02','2009-01-02',null,'Rechazado','mal pago',7);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (15,'2009-01-09','2009-01-12','2009-01-11','Entregado',NULL,7);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (16,'2009-01-06','2009-01-07','2009-01-15','Entregado',NULL,7);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (17,'2009-01-08','2009-01-09','2009-01-11','Entregado','mal estado',7);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (18,'2009-01-05','2009-01-06','2009-01-07','Entregado',NULL,9);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (19,'2009-01-18','2009-02-12',NULL,'Pendiente','entregar en murcia',9);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (20,'2009-01-20','2009-02-15',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,9);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (21,'2009-01-09','2009-01-09','2009-01-09','Rechazado','mal pago',9);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (22,'2009-01-11','2009-01-11','2009-01-13','Entregado',NULL,9);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (23,'2008-12-30','2009-01-10',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido fue anulado por el cliente',5);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (24,'2008-07-14','2008-07-31','2008-07-25','Entregado',NULL,14);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (25,'2009-02-02','2009-02-08',NULL,'Rechazado','El cliente carece de saldo en la cuenta asociada',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (26,'2009-02-06','2009-02-12',NULL,'Rechazado','El cliente anula la operacion para adquirir mas producto',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (27,'2009-02-07','2009-02-13',NULL,'Entregado','El pedido aparece como entregado pero no sabemos en que fecha',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (28,'2009-02-10','2009-02-17','2009-02-20','Entregado','El cliente se queja bastante de la espera asociada al producto',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (29,'2008-08-01','2008-09-01','2008-09-01','Rechazado','El cliente no está conforme con el pedido',14);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (30,'2008-08-03','2008-09-03','2008-08-31','Entregado',NULL,13);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (31,'2008-09-04','2008-09-30','2008-10-04','Rechazado','El cliente ha rechazado por llegar 5 dias tarde',13);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (32,'2007-01-07','2007-01-19','2007-01-27','Entregado','Entrega tardia, el cliente puso reclamacion',4);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (33,'2007-05-20','2007-05-28',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido fue anulado por el cliente',4);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (34,'2007-06-20','2008-06-28','2008-06-28','Entregado','Pagado a plazos',4);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (35,'2008-03-10','2009-03-20',NULL,'Rechazado','Limite de credito superado',4);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (36,'2008-10-15','2008-12-15','2008-12-10','Entregado',NULL,14);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (37,'2008-11-03','2009-11-13',NULL,'Pendiente','El pedido nunca llego a su destino',4);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (38,'2009-03-05','2009-03-06','2009-03-07','Entregado',NULL,19);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (39,'2009-03-06','2009-03-07','2009-03-09','Pendiente',NULL,19);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (40,'2009-03-09','2009-03-10','2009-03-13','Rechazado',NULL,19);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (41,'2009-03-12','2009-03-13','2009-03-13','Entregado',NULL,19);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (42,'2009-03-22','2009-03-23','2009-03-27','Entregado',NULL,19);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (43,'2009-03-25','2009-03-26','2009-03-28','Pendiente',NULL,23);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (44,'2009-03-26','2009-03-27','2009-03-30','Pendiente',NULL,23);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (45,'2009-04-01','2009-03-04','2009-03-07','Entregado',NULL,23);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (46,'2009-04-03','2009-03-04','2009-03-05','Rechazado',NULL,23);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (47,'2009-04-15','2009-03-17','2009-03-17','Entregado',NULL,23);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (48,'2008-03-17','2008-03-30','2008-03-29','Entregado','Según el Cliente, el pedido llegó defectuoso',26);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (49,'2008-07-12','2008-07-22','2008-07-30','Entregado','El pedido llegó 1 día tarde, pero no hubo queja por parte de la empresa compradora',26);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (50,'2008-03-17','2008-08-09',NULL,'Pendiente','Al parecer, el pedido se ha extraviado a la altura de Sotalbo (Ávila)',26);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (51,'2008-10-01','2008-10-14','2008-10-14','Entregado','Todo se entregó a tiempo y en perfecto estado, a pesar del pésimo estado de las carreteras.',26);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (52,'2008-12-07','2008-12-21',NULL,'Pendiente','El transportista ha llamado a Eva María para indicarle que el pedido llegará más tarde de lo esperado.',26);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (53,'2008-10-15','2008-11-15','2008-11-09','Entregado','El pedido llega 6 dias antes',13);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (54,'2009-01-11','2009-02-11',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,14);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (55,'2008-12-10','2009-01-10','2009-01-11','Entregado','Retrasado 1 dia por problemas de transporte',14);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (56,'2008-12-19','2009-01-20',NULL,'Rechazado','El cliente a anulado el pedido el dia 2009-01-10',13);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (57,'2009-01-05','2009-02-05',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,13);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (58,'2009-01-24','2009-01-31','2009-01-30','Entregado','Todo correcto',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (59,'2008-11-09','2008-11-14','2008-11-14','Entregado','El cliente paga la mitad con tarjeta y la otra mitad con efectivo, se le realizan dos facturas',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (60,'2008-12-22','2008-12-27','2008-12-28','Entregado','El cliente comprueba la integridad del paquete, todo correcto',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (61,'2009-01-15','2009-01-20',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente llama para confirmar la fecha - Esperando al proveedor',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (62,'2009-01-20','2009-01-27',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente requiere que el pedido se le entregue de 16:00h a 22:00h',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (63,'2009-01-22','2009-01-27',NULL,'Pendiente','El cliente requiere que el pedido se le entregue de 9:00h a 13:00h',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (64,'2009-01-24','2009-01-31','2009-01-30','Entregado','Todo correcto',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (65,'2009-02-02','2009-02-08',NULL,'Rechazado','El cliente carece de saldo en la cuenta asociada',1);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (66,'2009-02-06','2009-02-12',NULL,'Rechazado','El cliente anula la operacion para adquirir mas producto',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (67,'2009-02-07','2009-02-13',NULL,'Entregado','El pedido aparece como entregado pero no sabemos en que fecha',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (68,'2009-02-10','2009-02-17','2009-02-20','Entregado','El cliente se queja bastante de la espera asociada al producto',3);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (74,'2009-01-14','2009-01-22',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido no llego el dia que queria el cliente por fallo del transporte',15);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (75,'2009-01-11','2009-01-13','2009-01-13','Entregado','El pedido llego perfectamente',15);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (76,'2008-11-15','2008-11-23','2008-11-23','Entregado',NULL,15);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (77,'2009-01-03','2009-01-08',NULL,'Pendiente','El pedido no pudo ser entregado por problemas meteorologicos',15);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (78,'2008-12-15','2008-12-17','2008-12-17','Entregado','Fue entregado, pero faltaba mercancia que sera entregada otro dia',15);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (79,'2009-01-12','2009-01-13','2009-01-13','Entregado',NULL,28);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (80,'2009-01-25','2009-01-26',NULL,'Pendiente','No terminó el pago',28);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (81,'2009-01-18','2009-01-24',NULL,'Rechazado','Los producto estaban en mal estado',28);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (82,'2009-01-20','2009-01-29','2009-01-29','Entregado','El pedido llego un poco mas tarde de la hora fijada',28);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (83,'2009-01-24','2009-01-28',NULL,'Entregado',NULL,28);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (89,'2007-10-05','2007-12-13','2007-12-10','Entregado','La entrega se realizo dias antes de la fecha esperada por lo que el cliente quedo satisfecho',35);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (90,'2009-02-07','2008-02-17',NULL,'Pendiente','Debido a la nevada caída en la sierra, el pedido no podrá llegar hasta el día ',27);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (91,'2009-03-18','2009-03-29','2009-03-27','Entregado','Todo se entregó a su debido tiempo, incluso con un día de antelación',27);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (92,'2009-04-19','2009-04-30','2009-05-03','Entregado','El pedido se entregó tarde debido a la festividad celebrada en España durante esas fechas',27);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (93,'2009-05-03','2009-05-30','2009-05-17','Entregado','El pedido se entregó antes de lo esperado.',27);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (94,'2009-10-18','2009-11-01',NULL,'Pendiente','El pedido está en camino.',27);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (95,'2008-01-04','2008-01-19','2008-01-19','Entregado',NULL,35);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (96,'2008-03-20','2008-04-12','2008-04-13','Entregado','La entrega se retraso un dia',35);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (97,'2008-10-08','2008-11-25','2008-11-25','Entregado',NULL,35);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (98,'2009-01-08','2009-02-13',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,35);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (99,'2009-02-15','2009-02-27',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (100,'2009-01-10','2009-01-15','2009-01-15','Entregado','El pedido llego perfectamente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (101,'2009-03-07','2009-03-27',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido fue rechazado por el cliente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (102,'2008-12-28','2009-01-08','2009-01-08','Entregado','Pago pendiente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (103,'2009-01-15','2009-01-20','2009-01-24','Pendiente',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (104,'2009-03-02','2009-03-06','2009-03-06','Entregado',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (105,'2009-02-14','2009-02-20',NULL,'Rechazado','el producto ha sido rechazado por la pesima calidad',30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (106,'2009-05-13','2009-05-15','2009-05-20','Pendiente',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (107,'2009-04-06','2009-04-10','2009-04-10','Entregado',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (108,'2009-04-09','2009-04-15','2009-04-15','Entregado',NULL,16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (109,'2006-05-25','2006-07-28','2006-07-28','Entregado',NULL,38);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (110,'2007-03-19','2007-04-24','2007-04-24','Entregado',NULL,38);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (111,'2008-03-05','2008-03-30','2008-03-30','Entregado',NULL,36);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (112,'2009-03-05','2009-04-06','2009-05-07','Pendiente',NULL,36);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (113,'2008-10-28','2008-11-09','2009-01-09','Rechazado','El producto ha sido rechazado por la tardanza de el envio',36);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (114,'2009-01-15','2009-01-29','2009-01-31','Entregado','El envio llego dos dias más tarde debido al mal tiempo',36);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (115,'2008-11-29','2009-01-26','2009-02-27','Pendiente',NULL,36);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (116,'2008-06-28','2008-08-01','2008-08-01','Entregado',NULL,38);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (117,'2008-08-25','2008-10-01',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido ha sido rechazado por la acumulacion de pago pendientes del cliente',38);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (118,'2009-02-15','2009-02-27',NULL,'Pendiente',NULL,16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (119,'2009-01-10','2009-01-15','2009-01-15','Entregado','El pedido llego perfectamente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (120,'2009-03-07','2009-03-27',NULL,'Rechazado','El pedido fue rechazado por el cliente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (121,'2008-12-28','2009-01-08','2009-01-08','Entregado','Pago pendiente',16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (122,'2009-04-09','2009-04-15','2009-04-15','Entregado',NULL,16);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (123,'2009-01-15','2009-01-20','2009-01-24','Pendiente',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (124,'2009-03-02','2009-03-06','2009-03-06','Entregado',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (125,'2009-02-14','2009-02-20',NULL,'Rechazado','el producto ha sido rechazado por la pesima calidad',30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (126,'2009-05-13','2009-05-15','2009-05-20','Pendiente',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (127,'2009-04-06','2009-04-10','2009-04-10','Entregado',NULL,30);
INSERT INTO pedido VALUES (128,'2008-11-10','2008-12-10','2008-12-29','Rechazado','El pedido ha sido rechazado por el cliente por el retraso en la entrega',38);
    
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (1,'PayPal','ak-std-000001','2008-11-10',2000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (1,'PayPal','ak-std-000002','2008-12-10',2000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (3,'PayPal','ak-std-000003','2009-01-16',5000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (3,'PayPal','ak-std-000004','2009-02-16',5000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (3,'PayPal','ak-std-000005','2009-02-19',926);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (4,'PayPal','ak-std-000006','2007-01-08',20000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (4,'PayPal','ak-std-000007','2007-01-08',20000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (4,'PayPal','ak-std-000008','2007-01-08',20000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (4,'PayPal','ak-std-000009','2007-01-08',20000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (4,'PayPal','ak-std-000010','2007-01-08',1849);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (5,'Transferencia','ak-std-000011','2006-01-18',23794);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (7,'Cheque','ak-std-000012','2009-01-13',2390);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (9,'PayPal','ak-std-000013','2009-01-06',929);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (13,'PayPal','ak-std-000014','2008-08-04',2246);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (14,'PayPal','ak-std-000015','2008-07-15',4160);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (15,'PayPal','ak-std-000016','2009-01-15',2081);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (15,'PayPal','ak-std-000035','2009-02-15',10000);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (16,'PayPal','ak-std-000017','2009-02-16',4399);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (19,'PayPal','ak-std-000018','2009-03-06',232);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (23,'PayPal','ak-std-000019','2009-03-26',272);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (26,'PayPal','ak-std-000020','2008-03-18',18846);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (27,'PayPal','ak-std-000021','2009-02-08',10972);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (28,'PayPal','ak-std-000022','2009-01-13',8489);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (30,'PayPal','ak-std-000024','2009-01-16',7863);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (35,'PayPal','ak-std-000025','2007-10-06',3321);
INSERT INTO pago VALUES (38,'PayPal','ak-std-000026','2006-05-26',1171);
```

Esta es la consulta que deseo hacer:

**Esta consula trata de devolver un listado con los clientes que han realizado algún pedido, pero no han realizado ningún pago**

```
Select c.nombre_cliente
from cliente c
Inner Join pedido p on(c.codigo_cliente = p.codigo_pedido)
Inner Join pago pa on(c.codigo_cliente = pa.codigo_cliente)
where pa.codigo_cliente = null;
```

Y me da en blanco el resultado

Comment: Te sale en blanco por que no se cumple la condición. Haz un `SELECT *
from cliente c
Inner Join pedido p on(c.codigo_cliente = p.codigo_pedido)
Inner Join pago pa on(c.codigo_cliente = pa.codigo_cliente)` y verás que en ningún momento **codigo_cliente** tiene valor nulo.

Comment: El inner join con la tabla pago debe ser un left join para que se cumpla pa.codigo_cliente = null

Comment: Dandole la razón a @Vicent, debes usar **Left** en vez de **Inner** también veo que `Inner Join pedido p on(**c.codigo_cliente = p.codigo_pedido**)` no tiene mucho sentido... El `p.codigo_pedido` debería ser `p.codigo_cliente`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al realizar un `INNER JOIN` por `codigo_cliente` solo te aparecerán los clientes que tienen pagos.

Para solucionarlo debes hacer un `LEFT JOIN`

```
Select c.nombre_cliente
from cliente c
Inner Join pedido p on(c.codigo_cliente = p.codigo_pedido)
LEFTO JOIN pago pa on(c.codigo_cliente = pa.codigo_cliente)
where pa.codigo_cliente = null;
```

Con esto, traes todos los clientes con pedido, tengan o no pagos, los que no tienen pagos los identificas por el `WHERE pa.codigo_cliente = null`